# Html select tag issue

Tags: php

There are two field in my form.

1) Html select field item ( From mysql database)
2) Name box.

If a user select a item from html select tag and forgot to write his/her name then with php it's say..

```
* Your username required
```

BUT then it's doesn't show the select item which user **selected**.. it's show again **Select...** That's why another error message appear..

```
* Please select your item.
```

How do i show this selected item with php?

**Html form:**

```
<tr>    
<td>Class</td>
<td>
<select class="td" name="class">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Select..</option>
    <?php
    include_once("../../toplevel/content/manage/dbcon/dbcon.php");
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM class");
    while($re = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
$re_class = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($re['c_name']));      
        echo "<option value='$re_class'> $re_class </option>";
    }
    ?>  
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td><input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['uname'])) echo 
$_POST['uname']; ?>" name="uname" class="td" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

I can do this for Name filed But how do i do this for the select field ?
Thanks a lot.
Shibbir

Comment: How can you do what? It's quite unclear.

Comment: @Jack Spairow.. 2 html form box.. one is list of item with select tag, another is name field box. If user select a item but forgot to put his username then it's say "username required" BUT it's doesn't show the selected item which user select from html select tag. I want to show those selected item which user select.. Hope its make sense...

Comment: @Jack Spairow.. do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <tr>    
    <td>Class</td>
    <td>
    <select class="td" name="class">
        <option value="">Select..</option>
        <?php
        include_once("../../toplevel/content/manage/dbcon/dbcon.php");
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM class");
        while($re = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
           $re_class = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($re['c_name'])); 
           $sel='';
           if($re_class==$_POST['class'])  {
             $sel='selected="selected"';
           }   
            echo "<option value='$re_class' ".$sel."> $re_class </option>";
        }
        ?>  
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['uname'])) echo 
    $_POST['uname']; ?>" name="uname" class="td" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
```

Did u mean this?

Comment: Yes @Sujal EXACTLY WHAT I WANT. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <tr>    
  <td>Class</td>
<td>
<select class="td" name="class" onchange="this.form.submit();">
<option selected="selected" value="">Select..</option>
<?php
include_once("../../toplevel/content/manage/dbcon/dbcon.php");
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM class");
while($re = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$re_class[] = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($re['c_name']));      

}
?>  
<?php for($i = 0; $i < count($re_class); $i++) { ?>

<?php echo "<option value='$re_class[$i]'";
if($re_class[$i] == $_POST['class']) { echo "selected=selected"; } ?> <?php echo ">" . $re_class[$i] . </option>"; ?>

<?php } ?>
   </select>
   </td>
   </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>Name</td>
 <td><input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['uname'])) echo 
     $_POST['uname']; ?>" name="uname" class="td" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
```

**Edit** It seems like you want the option value to be selected if the current `$_POST` variable equals an option in your `$re_class` array.

Comment: It's doesn't working.. It's still show "select.." after select a item from select tag.

Comment: edited it. It should now take you to the page you need to go to,

Comment: you have to relocate `selected="selected"` to the `<option>` which the user chose.

Comment: What's Wrong @RPM after select item it's re-loading the page!

Comment: What do you want to do with the option values?

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>    
<td>Class</td>
<td>
<select class="td" name="class">
    <option value="">Select..</option>
    <?php
    include_once("../../toplevel/content/manage/dbcon/dbcon.php");
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM class");
    while($re = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $re_class = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($re['c_name']));
        if(isset($_POST['class'])){
            echo '<option '.($_POST['class']==$re_class?'selected':'').' value='.$re_class.'>'.$re_class.'</option>';
        }else{
            echo '<option value='.$re_class.'>'.$re_class.'</option>';
        }
    }
    ?>  
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td><input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['uname'])) echo 
$_POST['uname']; ?>" name="uname" class="td" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

Comment: Sorry it's doesn't show selected item it's only show "Username required if i put blank"..